# Function Google Script to display Bitly Count Links on a cell of spreadsheet Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, bit.ly, url-shortener

How can a create a function that calls this API URL of bitly https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks to get the number of clicks of one given link.

When i call i get this:
{"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "unit_reference_ts": null, "tz_offset": -5, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 0}, "status_txt": "OK"}

I want to read a link in one cell and put the result in another cell.

I dont want to use import function, because it has a limit. You cant use more than x number on each sheet

Comment: Is missing a google-apps-script tag? Can you post some code, or details of what you have found.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I've found for parsing JSON is [this ImportJSON script](https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/tree/master/scripts/ImportJSON).